# Is there a way to programmatically have 4 cards per row?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, bootstrap-4, flask-wtforms

I am currently working with Python Flask and Bootstrap. 
I  am looking to get it so that if there are 4 cards in one row, it will automatically create a new row.

Issue i am having just now is the more posts I have the longer and thinner the rows cards get. 
Current code:

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="card-deck">
        {# Go through each forum post #}
        {% for post in forum_posts.items %}

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <span class="badge badge-info">{{ post.cat }}</span>

                    <h3 class="card-title"><a class="card-title"
                                              href="{{ url_for('forum_posts.view_post', forum_post_id=post.id) }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
                    </h3>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Written by: {{ post.author.username }}</h6>
                    <p>{{ post.text[:100] }}...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <a href="{{ url_for('forum_posts.view_post', forum_post_id=post.id) }}"
                       class="btn btn-primary">Read
                        Blog Post</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could code this on the python side so that it makes it easier in jinja2, using an array of arrays:

```
>>> arr = [0,1,2,3,4,.....,102]
>>> forum_posts.items = []
>>> for i in range(int(len(arr)/4)):
        j = i * 4
        forum_posts.items.append([arr[j], arr[j+1], arr[j+2], arr[j+3]])
        # needs an error trap for IndexError on 103
```

Then in jinja2: you can double loop:

```
{% for row in forum_posts.items %}
    {% for item in row %}
         {# HTML here for a new row of at most 4 cards #}
```

There is a way of doing the same kind of thing in jinja2 using variable loop counters and setting new row HTML if for example the new loop index is an exact multiple of 4:

```
{% for i, post in enumerate(forum_posts.items) %}
    {% if i % 4 == 0 %}
        {# new row code #}
    {% else %}
        {# regular row code %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```